# DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly still needs authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I encountered this issue even though I didn't set authentication requirements in my settings.py. When I view the /products/ endpoint as anonymous user it still asks for authentication but when I view the endpoint as authenticated user it behaves as expected

here's my viewset where I'm using the permission

```
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter]
    filterset_class = ProductFilter
    pagination_class = DefaultPagination
    permission_classes = [DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly]
    search_fields = ["title", "description"]
    ordering_fields = ["unit_price", "last_update"]

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if OrderItem.objects.filter(product_id=kwargs["pk"]).count() > 0:
            return Response(
                {
                    "error": "Product cannot be deleted because it is associated with an order item."
                },
                status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED,
            )
        return super().destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

here's my settings.py file

```
"""
Django settings for storefront project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
from datetime import timedelta

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "django-insecure-hs6j037urx6iav+7#10%-vu4l4f5@@-1_zo)oft4g7$vf2$jmp"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django_filters",
    "rest_framework",
    "djoser",
    "playground",
    "debug_toolbar",
    "store",
    "tags",
    "likes",
    "core",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

INTERNAL_IPS = [
    # ...
    "127.0.0.1",
    # ...
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "storefront.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "storefront.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "storefront_new",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "password",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": "5432",
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "/static/"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",
    ),
    "COERCE_DECIMAL_TO_STRING": False,
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("JWT",),
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "core.User"

DJOSER = {
    "SERIALIZERS": {
        "user_create": "core.serializers.UserCreateSerializer",
        "current_user": "core.serializers.UserSerializer",
    }
}
```